# Docker: Merged folder deleted automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, docker

I was trying to change the content of the HTML folder from the overlay2 layer, for this, I have deleted the HTML folder and recreated it, but after this MERGED folder gets deleted automatically and my website suddenly got out of reach.

Please anybody can help me to restore this.

Thanks,
Pankaj

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Pankaj. Please provide more information regarding your setup and your problem. From the given information it is hard to understand what your setup is, what you did and what your question is.

Comment: Thanks, Adebasi for your quick response.

I am new in Docker overlay, Actually, it is an existing setup with a docker overlay and has multiple layers setup.

Following was the path of the application in my setup and was working.
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e2772ad58d59587a7eed721fd1ac610c598482d1c5efe7422668943863c17745/merged/usr/share/nginx/html

I was trying to upload a new compiled code by deleting and again creating an "HTML" folder, just after this "merged" folder automatically deleted and website stop working, because webserver was pointed on that location only.

Comment: This is ReactJs (frontend) and Ruby on Rails (backend) based web application.

Comment: You can edit your question to improve your question and explain your setup. Normally you should not change anything directly in the /var/lib/docker folders. If you want to update your website, you should create a new image and start a container from it. For local development you can mount directories. If it is necessary to change something in your container you can do this using commands like `docker exec` or `docker cp`

Comment: I work around both commands but nothing is working. And the main problem is the Nginx server is down and I am not able to start it because there is no service for the Nginx server. 

I found that the Nginx server is installed under Docker layer (/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0d54dc7ef9172383699efca4c84282b697936ace9f997a3b844c503b10ecf373/diff/etc/nginx/) 

When I check "docker ps", it gives an empty result. This means no any container is running.

Suggest me How can I start the Nginx server.